# How to encode for a dict

Tags: python, encoding

I have the following dict:

`dict = {"es-ES": "Capítulo "}`.

However, when I try to use the dict, I get the following error:

`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file.`.

I looked into the massive Python unicode docs ( http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html ), but haven't been able to figure this out yet. How would I 'encode' the dict so I could call `dict['es-ES']`? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try going to the link it gave you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

(Assuming you are using UTF-8), to the top of your Python file and you will be able to use Unicode without issue.  See [the Python docs on unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code).

<sub>* Also, don't use `dict` as a variable name - you'll shadow the [built-in type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) of the same name</sub>

Comment: >Alternately, if you are using Python 2.x, you can prefix your strings with u to treat them as Unicode. AFAIK, prefixing a string with `u` will not treat it as unicode - it will try to create an unicode object, but the encoding error will still remain.

Comment: @warvariuc - quite correct!  I have removed the offending lines.  Thanks for the reminder!